# Why can't I use conn.ok() from net.go?

Tags: go

I'm coming at Golang from a Python background and I am trying to wrap my head around various new concepts.

One thing I have come across is this function in net.go:

```
func (c *conn) ok() bool { return c != nil && c.fd != nil }
```

This function is called by multiple net.go methods, e.g. conn.Read:

```
// Read implements the Conn Read method.
func (c *conn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {     
if !c.ok() {        
    return 0, syscall.EINVAL
}
```

I am trying to understand how the `ok()` method can be called on conn, despite the fact that `ok()` does **not** appear to be an interface of conn.

Certainly I do not seem to be able to call `ok()` from my client code:

```
func main() {
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "www.reddit.com:80")
if err != nil {
    os.Exit(-1)
}
fmt.Println(&conn.ok())
}
```

Output:

```
./server.go:14:22: conn.ok undefined (type net.Conn has no field or method ok)
```

Any pointers appreciated...

Comment: The interface is named `Conn`, which is distinct from the type `conn` (lowercase).

Answer (score 2):

From Go document :

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. **An identifier is exported if the first character of the
>   identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter**

So , ok function is not exported and you can't access it outside of net package.

Answer (score 2):

Go does not use public/private keywords for visibility of an identifier. If the initial character is an upper case letter, the identifier is exported(public); otherwise it is not:

- upper case initial letter: Name is visible to clients of package
- otherwise: name (or _Name) is not visible to clients of package

Answer (score 0):

There is no field or method like ok in net.Conn that what the error says and that is correct. 
when you try to read and write into the conn , you would get err and number of bytes read or write it into the connection.